# Is a vehicle solely for personal use required to be licensed?

Tags: driving, vehicle, frivolous-arguments

Please explain

> "The term “motor vehicle” means every description of carriage or other
>   contrivance propelled or drawn by mechanical power and used for
>   commercial purposes on the highways in the transportation of
>   passengers, passengers and property, or property or cargo. 18 U.S.
>   Code § 31 - Definitions | US Law | LII / Legal Information Institute"

Comment: That section of US law is about crimes such blowing up commercial vehicles. The definition distinguished cars and trucks from trains, horses and boats. Licensing is irrelevant to that part of the law.

Answer (score 5):

You are required by *state law* to register and license a personal (or commercial) vehicle because state laws govern vehicle licensing, not the federal government as you cite. See [Motor vehicle registration - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_vehicle_registration).

States have the right, well established in case law, to require registration, taxation and insurance for all vehicles on all public roads.

The various websites and "sovereign citizen" arguments on the web that say you don't need to register or license a vehicle are wrong.

In some special cases, states issue waivers for what are known as farm or ranch vehicles driven solely on private property, and those cases may or may not pay taxes or require insurance.

Answer (score -3):

I think you are wrong.
Any state requiring registration as mandatory
Is in violation of US Code Title 34 § 12611 (c)(1).
per US Constitution ArtVI.C2.1 when there is a conflict between State Legislation and Congressional Law, the State Legislation will not prevail. State Judges are bound by the US Constitution to uphold this Citizen Right.

A US Citizen is not required to register a vehicle as car plates are a voluntary theft deterrent according to the US Code. US Constitution ArtVI.C2.1 places a precedence on Federal Law meaning that Federal Law always over rides State Legislation, Municipal Codes or City Ordinances when there is a conflict.
As US Code Title 34 and US Code Title 49 both make vehicle license plates a voluntary theft deterrent, State Legislation can not make vehicle registration mandatory for a US Citizen. The US Constitution defines Citizen Rights, one of those rights is to be able to rely on the unalienable rights listed in the US Constitution to be valid within the entirety of the whole United States and another is to be able to rely on Congressional Law as valid and in force throughout the entire United States. Relying on Federal Law as “always correct” simplifies maintaining lawful conduct for a US Citizen.

Comment: This looks like ChatGPT

Comment: @Heddy it looks like drivel

Comment: @Heddy, and Dale M.  are you a bot troll? I don't see any helpful responses.